# PHP preg_replace - finding the replacement from an array using the match as the key

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string which can contain multiple matches (any word surrounded by percentage marks) and an array of replacements - they key of each replacement being the match of the regex. Some code will probably explain that better...

```
$str = "PHP %foo% my %bar% in!";
$rep = array(
  'foo' => 'does',
  'bar' => 'head'
);
```

The desired result being:

```
$str = "PHP does my head in!"
```

I have tried the following, none of which work:

```
$res = preg_replace('/\%([a-z_]+)\%/', $rep[$1], $str);
$res = preg_replace('/\%([a-z_]+)\%/', $rep['$1'], $str);
$res = preg_replace('/\%([a-z_]+)\%/', $rep[\1], $str);
$res = preg_replace('/\%([a-z_]+)\%/', $rep['\1'], $str);
```

Thus I turn to Stack Overflow for help. Any takers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/%([a-z_]+)%/e', '$rep["$1"]', $str);
```

gives:

```
PHP does my head in!
```

See [the docs for the modifier 'e'](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: The 'e' modifier is "deprecated and use is highly discouraged" since PHP 5.5. according to the docs cited in this answer. An alternative solution using preg_replace_callback() is presented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237882/preg-replace-using-pattern-as-index-of-replacement-data-array)

Comment: And the 'e' modifier is REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the modifier "e" is deprecated. There are security issues.
Alternatively, you can use the preg_replace_callback.

```
$res = preg_replace_callback('/\%([a-z_]+)\%/', 
                             function($match) use ($rep) { return  $rep[$match[1]]; },
                             $str );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the eval modifier...

```
$res = preg_replace('/\%([a-z_]+)\%/e', "\$rep['$1']", $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an alternative to preg_replace():

```
$str = "PHP %foo% my %bar% in!";
$rep = array(
  'foo' => 'does',
  'bar' => 'head'
);


function maskit($val) {
    return '%'.$val.'%';
}

$result = str_replace(array_map('maskit',array_keys($rep)),array_values($rep),$str);
echo $result;
```